# Hex String Replacement Using sed

Tags: sed

I'm having some trouble getting sed to do a find/replace of some hex characters.  I want to replace all instances within a file of the following hexadecimal string:

```
0x0D4D5348
```

with the following hexadecimal string:

```
0x0D0A4D5348
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: I'm trying to do a hex find/replace.  The input file does not have the literal value of "0x0D4D5348" in it, but it does have the ASCII representation of that in it.

Answer (score 42):

*GNU sed v3.02.80, GNU sed v1.03, and HHsed v1.5 by Howard Helman
all support the notation `\xNN`, where "NN" are two valid hex numbers, 00-FF.*

Here is how to replace a HEX sequence in your binary file:

```sh
$ sed 's/\x0D\x4D\x53\x48/\x0D\x0A\x4D\x53\x48/g' file > temp; rm file; mv temp file
```

As @sputnik pointed out, you can use sed's `in place` functionality. One caveat though, if you use it on OS/X, you'd have to add an empty set of quotes:

```sh
$ sed '' 's/\x0D\x4D\x53\x48/\x0D\x0A\x4D\x53\x48/g' file
```

As sed `in place` on OS/X [takes a parameter](http://blog.mpdaugherty.com/2010/05/27/difference-with-sed-in-place-editing-on-mac-os-x-vs-linux/) to indicate what extension to add to the file name when making a backup, since it *does*  create a temp file first. But then.. OS/X's `sed` [doesn't support](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/AnExtremeExample/AnExtremeExample.html) `\x`.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response but I guess I wasn't quite clear.  I want to basically replace line endings 0x0D with 0x0D0A, however I only want to replace line endings where the beginning of the next line contains the characters "MSH" (which is 0x4D5348 in hex).  Does that make more sense?

Comment: It better to edit your original message than expect other readers to read all comments, looking to find your revised specification. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Question revised.

Comment: added a note about _binary_ values

Comment: Consider fixing your answer to include using sed -i rather than the > tmp ; rm file..business.

Comment: Since sed in OS X doesn't support \x, is there a different way to do this that will work in OS X?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Linux and OSX.

Replacing in-place:

```
sed -i '.bk' 's'/`printf "\x03"`'/foo/g' index.html
```

(See @Ernest's comment in the answer by @tolitius)

Comment: ancient is a relative term... this helped me out thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In OS/X system's Bash, You can use command like this:

```sh
# this command will crate a variable named a which contains '\r\n' in it
a=`echo -e "hello\r\nworld\r\nthe third line\r\n"`

echo "$a" | sed $'s/\r//g' | od -c
```

and now you can see the output characters :

```
0000000    h   e   l   l   o  \n   w   o   r   l   d  \n   t   h   e
0000020    t   h   i   r   d       l   i   n   e  \n
0000033
```

You should notice the difference between `'s/\r//g'` and `$'s/\r//g'`.
Based on the above practices, you can use command like this to replace hex String

```
echo "$a" | sed $'s/\x0d//g'  | od -c
```