# sed for checking hex syntax

Tags: sed, hex

I have follow file:

```
cat 123
# carriers mask for G1,G2 (96 - 168 kHz)
#       91, 4, {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF} \
# carriers mask for G3 (96 - 288 kHz)
#       91, 4, {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF} \
```

and want to check if have correct string in figural parentheses

I wrote following expression (check if every from 12 hex expression has correct syntax)

```
sed -r -n '/^.*91, 4, {\(0x[0-9A-F],\)\{11\}0x[0-9A-F]}.*/p' 123
sed: bad regex '^.*91, 4, {\(0x[0-9A-F],\)\{11\}0x[0-9A-F]}.*': Invalid content of \{\}
```

I tried to make expression in other way

```
sed -rne '/^.*91, 4, {0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F]}.*/ {p}' 123
sed: bad regex '^.*91, 4, {0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F],0x[0-9A-F]}.*': Invalid content of \{\}
```

Can anybody indicate where is my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7760752/1983854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no `-r` option and you were only checking for single digits. You could try something like:

```
sed -n '/91, 4, {\(0x[0-9A-F][0-9A-F],\)\{11\}0x[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]}/p' file
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that there is the small mistake in my expression )

Comment: You are welcome, it is sometimes the small things that can take most of the time ;)