# MySQL Convert latin1 to utf8, cp1252 0x80-0x9F wrong

Tags: mysql, utf-8, iconv, latin1, cp1252

Situation:
The latin1 database has been dump as latin1, converted via iconv to utf8 and restored as utf8_unicode_ci.

It seems every conversion went fine, excep those 0x80-0x9F from cp1252. i did not fully understand what mysql means by translating those character to unicode: [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-we-sets.html):

> latin1 is the default character set. MySQL's latin1 is the same as the Windows cp1252 character set. This means it is the same as the official ISO 8859-1 or IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) latin1, except that IANA latin1 treats the code points between 0x80 and 0x9f as “undefined,” whereas cp1252, and therefore MySQL's latin1, assign characters for those positions. For example, 0x80 is the Euro sign. For the “undefined” entries in cp1252, MySQL translates 0x81 to Unicode 0x0081, 0x8d to 0x008d, 0x8f to 0x008f, 0x90 to 0x0090, and 0x9d to 0x009d.

My tables are showing for example Â€ 0xC280 instead of € 0x80. so i guess i was mislead converting via

```
iconv -f latin1 -t utf8
```

instead i should have converted by

```
iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8
```

as my tests show. because the second line is doing the job right.

So the question is, if it is possible to correct those bad characters or do i have to dump the whole database?

EDIT: 
Is it possible to dump the bad database and convert via

```
  --default-character-set=utf8
  iconv -c -f utf-8 -t latin1
  iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8
```

then insert again into database? Would iconv -c help me out or do i lose information?

EDIT2:
It seems that it is possible to replace the broken chars one by one using:

```
update history set note = replace(note,unhex('C280'),unhex('E282AC'));
```

this will succesfully replace the wrong 2byte glibberish with the correct 3byte utf8.
of course this must be done for each varchar/text column and also for each broken char in the range
0x80-0x9F, which is unhandy.
So hopefully someone has a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand iconv command is based on C iconv function:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.11/iconv.3.html

> The iconv function returns the number of characters converted in a
>   non-reversible way during this call; reversible conversions are not
>   counted. In case of error, it sets errno and returns (size_t)(-1).

So you could try reverse conversions but according to documentation, result depends on return code of first conversion. Of course you could try binary replace invalid characters.

Comment: bad that i dont got any number as i didnt print the return code :(
how would your binary approach look like?

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760717/hex-string-replacement-using-sed