# Bash : Replace special character sequence

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 data file with some unexpected UTF-8 character sequence that breaks the processing of data. I need to replace this sequence with spaces or any safe character (data is from an external source):

```
In Hex: E2 80 8B (â€‹)
```

In a bash script, how can i replace this characters using a command line tool like `sed` or `replace` command? I have tried with:

```
sed 's/â€‹/   /g' file_1 > file_2
```

But it's not working (no data replaced). Is there a special syntax to specify the regular expression with "hex" characters instead of ascii characters?
It's posible to perform a "binary" replace using the 3-byte sequence?

Note: the file is UTF-8 encoded, so I think there is a problem searching the real sequence because is not in utf-8 (3 byte ASCII)

Comment: Can you try to explain how that byte sequence is "bad UTF-8"? And not to use the word "ascii"?

Comment: It's bad for me, I prefer to use "unexpected". The conversion process is deleting the character.

Comment: I've searched and find "Hex String Replacement Using sed" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760717/hex-string-replacement-using-sed and tried using the sequence `'s/\xE2\x80\x8B/ /g'` and it seems working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indeed the bytes are `0xE2`, `0x80` and `0x8B`, and it is utf-8 encoded text.

Then [it means](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128):

```
U+200B  ​   e2 80 8b    ZERO WIDTH SPACE
```

which is used to keep words together in some text.
And which could be printed in bash as:

```
$ printf 'zero width\U200Bspace \n'
zero widthspace 

$ printf 'zero width\U200Bspace \n' | xxd
00000000: 7a65 726f 2077 6964 7468 e280 8b73 7061  zero width...spa
00000010: 6365 200a
```

And you can remove; as sed actually understand bytes (not characters); with:

```
$ printf 'zero width\U200bspace\n' | sed 's/\xE2\x80\x8B/ /g'
zero width space
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, no idea of its existence. I can resolve the replacement problem  (that space is important in the application) with a hexadecimal search like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PHP function for filtering such symbols. That's not exactly what you want but still it can be run in console, just install PHP.
Replace `in.txt` with input file name, `out.txt` with output file name and run script (`php script_file.php`).
Hope it will be useful.

```
<?php
const INPUT_FILE_NAME = 'in.txt';
const OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'out.txt';

$finput = fopen(INPUT_FILE_NAME, 'r');
$foutput = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w');

while( ! feof($finput)) {
    $data = fgets($finput);
    fputs($foutput, strip_bad_utf8($data));
}

fclose($finput);
fclose($foutput);

function strip_bad_utf8($str)
{
    $str = sprintf('  %s  ', $str);
    $ret = '';
    for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($str);) {
        $tmp = $str{$i++};
        $ch = ord($tmp);
        if ($ch > 0x7F) {
            if ($ch < 0xC0) continue;
            elseif ($ch < 0xE0) $di = 1;
            elseif ($ch < 0xF0) $di = 2;
            elseif ($ch < 0xF8) $di = 3;
            elseif ($ch < 0xFC) $di = 4;
            elseif ($ch < 0xFE) $di = 5;
            else continue;

            for ($j = 0;$j < $di;$j++) {
                $tmp .= $ch = $str{$i + $j};
                $ch = ord($ch);
                if ($ch < 0x80 || $ch > 0xBF) continue 2;
            }
            $i += $di;
        }
        $ret .= $tmp;
    }
    return $ret;
}
?>
```

Here are two more functions for stripping 3 & 4 bytes UTF symbols:

```
function strip_3bytes_utf($text)
{
    return preg_replace("#([\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2})#i", '', $text);
}
function strip_4bytes_utf($text)
{
    return preg_replace("#([\xF0-\xF7]{1}[\x80-\xBF]{3})#i", '', $text);
}
```